# How to hide header outside of list when using search / filter and no results found in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, list

I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove a title from the following list after a search is complete. If there are no results inside the ul container (zebra-list) I would like to remove the title just before it.

E.g. If no books are found then Book section title is hidden // if no Journals are found then the Journal Section title is hidden.

> Book Section Title
>
> 2008 Book DVX
>
> 2007 Book 400 DVX
>
> 2006 Book 400 DVX
>
> Journal Section Title
>
> 2005 Journal DS 650
>
> 2004 Journal DS 650
>
> 2003 Journal DS 650
>
> 2002 Journal DS 650

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtList').on('keyup', function () {
        var value = this.value;
        $('.zebra-list li').hide().each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
                $(this).prevAll('.header').first().add(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have the following jsfiddle to show the problem. As you can see the titles remain after search above the empty lists. I would like to remove the titles if no items are displayed in the search.

[Js FIddle list with headers outside ul tag](http://jsfiddle.net/atpdejong/jv3v7nnL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this (comments in js below):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var allLi = $('.zebra-list li'),
     headings = $('.small-heading');   // cache vars for better performance

   $('#txtList').on('keyup', function() {
     var value = this.value;

     headings.hide(); // hide everything on keyup
     allLi.hide().each(function() {
       var li = $(this);
       if (li.text().search(value) > -1) {
         li.show();  // show current li
         li.parent().prev('.small-heading').show();  // show current li  heading (which is the previous small-heading of the parent ul)
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txtList' />
<h6 class="attention
 small-heading"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="color:#666;"> </i>
 Book Section Title</h6> 
<ul class="zebra-list fitment-padding">
  <li>2008 Book DVX</li>
  <li>2007 Book 400 DVX</li>
  <li>2006 Book 400 DVX</li>
</ul>
<h6 class="attention small-heading"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="color:#666;"> </i> Journal Section Title</h6> 
<ul class="zebra-list fitment-padding">
  <li>2005 Journal DS 650</li>
  <li>2004 Journal DS 650</li>
  <li>2003 Journal DS 650</li>
  <li>2002 Journal DS 650</li>
</ul>
```